# AJAX Search like nerddinner.com

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

can somebody tell me how it's needed to change the nerdDinner project, that the 'location-search' which is an JSON-Based Ajax call, works like
 http://www.nerddinner.com/#where=london

so that the search-location parameter will be added to the queryString and make the location browsable?

Thanks a lot, 
dan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found what I missed here. NerdDinner.com makes use of Sys.Application.AddHistoryPoint. A good example how to do this is in the asp.net mvc contact manager tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-32-cs.aspx